# Cannot access url for ActiveStorage::Attached::One instance when debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have this controller action:

```rb
def view_pdf
  redirect_to @report.pdf.url
end
```

When I access the route for `view_pdf` everything works as expected: it redirects to the pdf URL.

However, when I open a `pry-byebug` session with `byebug` I get this error when trying to access the URL:

```
@report.pdf.url
#=> *** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable
```

Also printing the URL works fine. I'm just confused why I cannot access it from the byebug console.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was as easy as including `ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable`:

```rb
include ActiveStorage::Blob::Analyzable
```

That made the trick.

Comment: including it where?

Comment: Include it in your controller @StevenAguilar